# Animations are sporadic on device

Tags: objective-c, ios

Animations (switching between viewControllers, scrolling tableView) on device are working with spurts but on simulator work fine. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy answer.
The only solution is to improve your code and make it lighter and more efficient. 
I ran into such problems too and I had no other option but to make my module work better.

The first suggestion would be to check for memory leaks (this one helped me: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ ). Fixing the leaks should give a little more memory to work with.

If you have this spurts on the first gen ipad... meh, it's so and so. but if you have them on the ipad2, then you really need to rewrite your code: use less elements, make less operations, maybe use some background operations to perform some threads so you can leave the main thread free to make the animations

Comment: Can it be leaks when I use ARC mode? I have spurts on iPhone 4... Don't understand.. I have tableView and each row is uiButton maybe problem in this?

Comment: If you show some code for the TableView delegate methods people may have suggestions for efficiency improvements

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling tableViews shouldn't be too big a problem since it has been quite efficiently designed. Did you implement the method heightForRowAtIndexPat: ? If so, and you have much data in your tableView, it gets extremely slow. In that case better use a fixed height or the table.